# Changing the EPL Statement at Runtime in Esper CEP

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

Currently I use Esper 8 in a Java environment to use CEP. Recently I asked myself if it is possible to change the EPL statements at runtime. For example, if you have an Esper CEP running with an EPL statement and you want to change this EPL statement without interrupting the CEP runtime. So the EPL statement is updated every x minutes by an SQL query with new EPL statements or the same. Is this even possible, or do I have to interrupt my Java runtime, change the EPL statement and restart the CEP every time I change the EPL statement?
Maybe this question sounds stupid but I don't know much about Esper CEP yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esper allows you to make changes to the sets of statements but not to the individual statement. In other words you can deploy (create EPL statements) and undeploy (remove EPL statements) as much as you want, on-the-fly and while running, however the existing EPL statements are not modifiable. Listeners, subscribers, variables, scripts, services etc. and extension code can of course change.

The reason it doesn't allow you to change a statement is that a statement may, and often does, have some state. Like say `select count(*) from Event`; This has count as a state. Assuming this was to change to `select count(*), avg(price) from Event`, now selecting the count and an average, the runtime doesn't actually remember any events so there is no way the average can be computed retrospectively.

CLARIFICATION: With "deploy" and "undeploy" I do NOT mean to deploy and undeploy the whole application. I mean simply to create some new EPL statements and to remove some EPL statements on-the-fly without any application stop/start.

Comment: My main thought was the uniforming of a stateless EPL statement. E.g. `select * from Event where x >3` to `select * from Event where x >4 and y >5`. 
Too bad something like this doesn't work. But wouldn't it work with stateful statements that the start time for the calculation of averages is the time at which the EPL was changed ?

Comment: Do you by any chance know a CEP solution where you can change the EPL statement at runtime? Is this possible with Apache Spark, Storm, Flink?

Comment: I don't know what "uniforming" is. I don't know what "something like this doesn't work" flame means.  Stateless statement can be undeployed and deployed anytime anyways so its a noissue.

Comment: Maybe you got the words "deploy" wrong. I have added a clarification.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that I can delete an EPStatement by the function removeAllListener() during runtime? and then replace it by creating a new EPStatement + UpdateListener? e.g. create my EPStatement/CEP as usual and add a delayed (SQL) query in my Java main, delete the old EPStatement via removeAllListener() and generate a new EPStatement with UpdateListener for my runtime?

Comment: No "removeAllListener" removes listeners to a statement and does not delete the statement. see doc and tutorials for more info